# Selenium WebdDriverException on using Tor

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, tor, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to build a scraping script using tor. I have installed tor and firefox on my WSL Ubuntu and I also made sure to uncomment the lines in the torrc file. but when I try to run my code:

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# signal TOR for a new connection
def switchIP():
    with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate()
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

# get a new selenium webdriver with tor as the proxy
def my_proxy(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT):
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    # Direct = 0, Manual = 1, PAC = 2, AUTODETECT = 4, SYSTEM = 5
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks",PROXY_HOST)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
    fp.update_preferences()
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    return webdriver.Firefox(options=options, firefox_profile=fp)

for x in range(10):
    proxy = my_proxy("127.0.0.1", 9050)
    proxy.get("https://whatsmyip.com/")
    html = proxy.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    print(soup.find("span", {"id": "ipv4"}))
    print(soup.find("span", {"id": "ipv6"}))
    switchIP()
```

I get the error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=proxyConnectFailure&u=https%3A//whatsmyip.com/&c=UTF-8&d=Firefox%20is%20configured%20to%20use%20a%20proxy%20server%20that%20is%20refusing%20connections.
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to connect to `https://amazon.com` but then it went into an infinite loop.

EDIT: also the connection keeps getting refused if I don't start tor from cmd? is that normal? Can I start tor from the python script itself?

Answer (score 0):

it worked after I restarted my WSL. Just made sure the torrc file was fine